# AngularJS: triggering the evaluation of bindings that include a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project in which the client needs to be able to change each and any string that we've used in the application. This need is similar to i18n needs, except that what we, the dev team, provided and the set of strings that the client may end up with after their modifications are both in the same language.

I have therefore implemented a filter, so that strings in html views are written as an Angular expression such as `{{'one.code.on.view1' | label }}`. The filter relies on a service that "holds the entire set of labels in memory", so to speak.

I've designed a simple UI for users to modify text labels: all labels are shown in an angular-ui-grid. Each line has the (non-modifiable) code and the (modifiable) label. Using the grid's inline edit feature, I save the modified label to the database. So far, so good.

My problem is that when saving the modified label to the database, I also update the entry of that label in the service that "holds labels" but unfortunately, in case the modified label were displayed on screen, the old value isn't updated.

My question is: how can I trigger an evaluation of bindings on the view? I have used every $timeout or $apply trick I knew but to no avail, which isn't very surprising since all the code runs within Angular contexts.

Here is the code of the filter and service: (for the sake of clarity, "libellé" is the French word for "label" even though we sometimes improperly use "label"; and 'scoop' is the name of the project, hence its use as a prefix)

```
function scoopLabelSceFn($resource, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    var rest = $resource('admin/libelle/list', {}, {});

    var labels = [];

    function loadAllLabels() {
        labels = rest.query({}, function(result) {

            var liste = [];
            for (var idx = 0; idx < result.length; ++idx) {
                var entry = result[idx];
                liste[entry.code] = entry.libelle;
            }               
            labels = liste;
        });
    }

    loadAllLabels();

    return {
        getLabels : function() {
            return labels;
        },

        reloadLabels : function() {
            loadAllLabels();
        },

        updateLabel : function(code, newValue) {
            labels[code] = newValue;
        }
    };

}

function scoopLabelFilterFn($log, scoopLabelService) {

    return function(input) {
        if (angular.isString(input)) {
            var libelles = scoopLabelService.getLabels();
            var res = libelles[input];
            if (res) {
                return res;
            }
            $log.log("scoopLabelFilter: no entry for: " + input);
            return input;
        }
        $log.log("scoopLabelFilter: incorrect parameter type");
        return "";
    };
}

module.filter("label", [ "$log", "scoopLabelService", scoopLabelFilterFn ]);
module.factory("scoopLabelService", [ "$resource", "$rootScope", "$timeout", scoopLabelSceFn ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing conceptually wrong with the code.

The way Angular treats filters has apparently changed somewhere on the 1.3.x branch. As a consequence, the code returning the filter function has to be modified.

Old code:

```
return function(input) {
...
```

Modified code:

```
function filterFn(input) {
...

filterFn.$stateful = true;
return filterFn;
```

With this, all expressions related to the filter are automatically reevaluated.